# I want to make a static library for other programs to use, but I don't know why it failed

Tags: c++, c

This is the source code of the file:

fileselector.h:

```cpp
#ifndef FILE_SELECTOR
#define FILE_SELECTOR

const char *open_file_dialog();

const char *save_file_dialog();

#endif
```

linux/fileselector.cpp:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include "../fileselector.h"
#include <iostream>

const char *open_file_dialog() {
    ...
}

const char *save_file_dialog() {
    ...
}
```

This is my static library production steps:

```sh
$ gcc linux/fileselector.cpp fileselector.h -c
$ ar rs libfileselector.a fileselector.o
```

This is a test using a static library:

main.c

```c
#include "fileselector.h"

int main() {
    open_file_dialog();
    return 0;
}
```

```sh
$ gcc main.c -L. -lfileselector -o main
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOTrMR8.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `open_file_dialog'
collect2: error：ld return 1
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to add `libfileselector.a` to the compiler to link it, don't you?

Comment: Why are you including `fileselector.h` in the `gcc` command? You don't want to have it there.

Comment: @JHBonarius That's what the `-l` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @ThomasJager so it's a typo: he's linking to the header file instead of the library, right?

Comment: I admit that in the compilation parameters of gcc, adding a header file is redundant, but it does not seem to affect the result.

Comment: Unless you have previously stored the library file in a *standard* folder, you must pass a `-L` flag in addition to the `-l` one to tell the linker where to find the library...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined a set of C++ functions but are using them from a C program.

Function names in C++ are mangled during the compilation phase to allow for multiple functions with the same name but different signatures to exist.  C programs don't do name mangling, so the compiled name of the library functions don't match the plain function name that the C program expects.

If you want C++ functions to be usable by a C program, you need to disable name mangling by adding `extern "C"` around the definitions and declarations.

So your C++ source file would look like this:

```
extern "C" {

const char *open_file_dialog() {
    ...
}

const char *save_file_dialog() {
    ...
}

}
```

And your header would look like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

const char *open_file_dialog();

const char *save_file_dialog();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The `#ifdef`'s in the header are needed because `extern "C"` is a C++ only feature.

Also, it's not necessary to list the header file when compiling.  Because it is included in the source file it is already being compiled.